# USB video capture adapter with syntek chipset driver for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, video-capture

I need driver for Windows 7 for syntek stk1150 USB Video Capture Device.

Any good place I can look for it?

I need 64 bit driver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the Syntek STK1150 is used in EasyCap devices. I have found a few links on the internet for Windows 7 x64 drivers:

[MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?zieze3mwlmu)

[MegaUpload](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=W64LW1DJ)

It looks like EasyCap doesn't provide very much direct support for these devices.